# Cross platform PDF organizer

Tags: pdf, cross-platform, knowledge-organization

I have a few thousands documents that I would like to organize and read from various devices, so I am looking for a cross platform PDF organizer. My needs are pretty simple:

- it should support at least MacOSX, Android and Linux
- it should allow me to attach to a paper at least: the authors, title, and some tags - then let me browse/search by tags or authors
- it should not crash with 10000+ documents and hundreds of tags
- it should not mess with my existing library - rather, it can keep its own metadata in a SQLite database, a JSON file or whatever
- however it does, it should be documented. I already have a lot of this information and I can write a Python script to put these info in whatever format is required
- I don't really care if it opens the files itself or if it uses external programs, but in case, I need support for PDF, PS and DJVU documents
- it can be free or payed, but just once - I'd rather not pay forever with a subscription
- finally, it should not force me to put my collection in cloud, but should work locally. I can manage the sync between devices myself

Is there anything like that?

Comment: Well, personally I use [miniCalOPe](https://codeberg.org/izzy/minicalope) for that – not sure if this will meet your needs. It's web based (self-hosted), so it can be used from any OS. I use it for my PDF documents locally – but also for my [eBook server](https://ebooks.qumran.org/) where it currently serves almost 11k of eBooks in different formats. All of your requirements listed are met. Might not be perfect, but worth a look I guess?

Comment: Thank you, it seems nice! I am not sure it will run on Android, though, but maybe there is some trick :-)

Comment: The idea is to run miniCalOPe on a Linux machine (with PHP and e.g. Apache or NGinX), and then access it from all your other devices via web browser. If you want to *install* miniCalOPe on an Android device, you'll need a webserver with PHP there; you can find [some candidates listed here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_server_web#group_414).

Comment: Yeah, I imagined that was the default way to go, but the thing is - I would like to be able to use this tool while on the go on my tablet. At home, I would just use a notebook. So I cannot depend on something running on my home network. I will try the way with Android servers. Thank you in any case for your suggestion!